# UIView Display Late If Creating It Programmatically with Auto Layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I'm stuck! I'm working on a viewController which is going to be a base for other viewControllers. Others will extend from it.

I want to create some view (like custom NavigationBar) with **programmatically constraints** for baseViewController and I created it.

So I have storyboard, there is a navigationController with a rootViewController (HomeViewController) and this homeViewController extend from baseViewController.

Here is my storyboard looks like;

[image: Storyboard scene]

So, my constraints are working! But the view which is created with programmatically constraints display after couple of second and its drive me crazy!

Here is how it looks when app first running;

[image]

And after couple of seconds my view appears;

[image]

I want to also share my codes. I am using visual format language to create constraints;

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
[self initializeBaseView];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Initialize BaseView

- (void)initializeBaseView{

    //Background View
    if (self.backgroundContainerView == nil) {
        self.backgroundContainerView = [UIView new];
        self.backgroundContainerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [self.view addSubview:self.backgroundContainerView];
        [self.view sendSubviewToBack:self.backgroundContainerView];
    }
    [self initConstraint_1];


    //Navigation Header View
    if(self.navigationBarContainerView == nil){
        self.navigationBarContainerView = [UIView new];
        self.navigationBarContainerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [self.navigationBarContainerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [self.view addSubview:self.navigationBarContainerView];

    }
    [self initConstraint_2];

    if (self.backgroundType==BackgroundTypeWhite) {
        //very light Gray
        [self.backgroundContainerView setBackgroundColor:APP_GRAY_COLOR_ATHENS];
    }

    [self initializeBaseStyle];
}

- (void)initializeBaseStyle{
    [self.navigationBarContainerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
}



#pragma mark - Initialize Constraints

- (void)initConstraint_1{
    // 1. Create a dictionary of views
    NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = @{@"firstView":self.backgroundContainerView};
    NSDictionary *metrics = @{@"vSpacing":@0, @"hSpacing":@0};

    // 2. Define the view Position and automatically the Size
    NSArray *constraint_POS_V = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-vSpacing-[firstView]-hSpacing-|"
                                                                        options:0
                                                                        metrics:metrics
                                                                          views:viewsDictionary];

    NSArray *constraint_POS_H = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-hSpacing-[firstView]-hSpacing-|"
                                                                        options:0
                                                                        metrics:metrics
                                                                          views:viewsDictionary];

    [self.view addConstraints:constraint_POS_V];
    [self.view addConstraints:constraint_POS_H];

}


- (void)initConstraint_2{
    NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = @{@"firstView": self.navigationBarContainerView, @"secondView": self.logoImage};
    NSDictionary *metrics = @{@"vSpacing":@74,
                              @"hSpacing":@0,
                              @"BottomSpacing":@60,
                              @"firstViewHeight":@64
                              };


    // 2. Define the view Position and automatically the Size (for the firstView)
    NSArray *constraint_POS_V = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[firstView(firstViewHeight)]"
                                                                        options:0
                                                                        metrics:metrics
                                                                          views:viewsDictionary];

    NSArray *constraint_POS_H = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-hSpacing-[firstView]-hSpacing-|"
                                                                        options:0
                                                                        metrics:metrics
                                                                          views:viewsDictionary];

    [self.view addConstraints:constraint_POS_V];
    [self.view addConstraints:constraint_POS_H];

}
```

I have plenty of questions;

- What is the reason could it be?
- Can I use storyboard when I want to
  create programmatically constraints?
- I'm using viewDidLoad to call methods for creating
  view and set constraints. Is viewDidLoad good place for that?
- What is the best practice for this scenario?
- How I can manage to initialize my view immediately as like as first picture?

I hope that's clear.
Thank you for your answers and I'm looking forward to hearing from you.

Comment: try doing it in viewDidAppear. ViewDidload is not the right place for dealing with views and autolayout

Comment: I don't know the reason why it takes 2 seconds for your view to display. What I can say is that your code looks very complex for what you are doing. Two suggestions: set up your constraints in the storyboard instead of in code, because it's much easier. Second, the navigation controller gives you a nav bar automatically, you shouldn't create a nav bar view. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/index.html

Comment: P.S. Your app looks like it's going to be cool!

Answer (score 0):

First if not mandatory then set constraints from IB. If mandatory then perform your task in viewDidAppear and on main thread if required.

Comment: It doesn't matter where you are giving constraints if you have good hand on autolayout.

Answer (score 0):

Call `setNeedsLayout` and `layoutIfNeeded` method just after constraints setting. It will work for you.

Comment: Nope it didn't work Richard. It has still comes after a couple of sec. @Richard G